# Broadcasting, multiple n*m returns instead of n*m element [Julia 1.0]

Tags: arrays, dataframe, scope, julia

Suppose I want to write a function that requires arrays of any length as argument inputs: 
e.g.,

```julia
f = function(x,y) 
  z = x * y
  outputs = DataFrame(x = x, y = y, z = z)
  return(outputs)
end
```

The return, `f.([1,2],[1,2])` is a 2-element array of two 1x3 DataFrames. But, in this scenario I want one 2x3 DataFrame.

I could accomplish this by defining z prior to a nested for loop:

```julia
f = function(x,y)
  z=fill(0,length(x))
  for i in 1:length(x)
   z[i] = x[i] * y[i]
  end
  outputs = DataFrame(x = x, y = y, z = z)
  return(outputs)
end
```

Here, `f([1,2],[1, 2])` gets me what I desire. But, the problems are that I have to define all in-function variables twice and add a for loop, while remembering to include the iterated variable, `i`. Is there something I'm missing? My question is, how do I get my desired n*m element as opposed to an n*m array...
 I tried to follow this [Julia blog post](https://julialang.org/blog/2017/01/moredots). Also [this Julia discussion post](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/loop-fusion-and-multiple-return-values/12210/2) specifically address the issue but I think the solutions were outdated for 1.0.

---- EDIT

Using a for loop could work as would using dots to denote element-wise operations.
The larger issue I'm concerned about is consistency.
Suppose I have two functions. One function (`f1`) returns one-dimensional output while the other (`f2`) has a two-dimensional output.

```julia
 function f1(x, y)
  z = x .* y
  DataFrame(x = x, y = y, z = z)
 end
 function f2(x, y)
  z = x * y
  return(z)
 end
```

Here the correct calls when `x = [1,2]` and `y = [1,2]` would be `f1([1,2], [1,2])` and `f2.([1,2], [1,2])`.
What I'm calling here as inconsistent is that (from the point of view of a user who doesn't know the internal function code), to get an output where `z` is the length of `x` and `y`, `.` is used with `f2` but not `f1`. The only workaround I can see is to define `z = .x * y` (or alternatively use a for each index loop) in `f2`. In that case, both `f1` and `f2` both can be called without a dot. Is that an appropriate solution? To be clear, what I am aiming for is that `f1` and `f2` are called identically by a user whether `x` and `y` are single or multiple element arrays. My preferences would be to have the user call both functions without a dot if `x` and `y` are single elements and with a `.`if each variable had multiple elements. This doesn't seem possible. Therefore, the part that I have to learn to live with is having to write many `.` or `[i]`'s in my functions (if I desire "consistency"). Correct?

Alternatively, I could add documentation that explicitly states that my functions which return one variable need to be called with `.` when arguments are of length>1 and functions that return a dataframe need not be called with `.` for any reason. 
[forgive any misuse of technical language; my background is ecology]

Comment: This is called _broadcasting_ in Julia, not loop fusion. You could edit you title to make that more clear to the readers.

Comment: @Justin can you use multiple dispatch for this? https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/methods/index.html

Comment: I ended up using multiple dispatch. I wasn't aware of this functionality. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
julia> function f(x, y)
           z = x .* y
           DataFrame(x = x, y = y, z = z)
       end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f([1,2], [1,2])
2×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ x │ y │ z │
├─────┼───┼───┼───┤
│ 1   │ 1 │ 1 │ 1 │
│ 2   │ 2 │ 2 │ 4 │
```

You could also write `f(x, y) = DataFrame(x = x, y = y, z = x .* y)` in short.

The way you wrote the function definition suggests that you know R. In Julia, as opposed to R, scalars and arrays are totally separated types (eg. `Float64` and `Vector{Float64}`), and have to be treated differently; but usually, just adding enough broadcasting at the right places works (and broadcasting works by putting a `.` after any function call or before any operator).

To be sure not to mix such things up, you can add types to the arguments: `f(x::Vector{Float64}, y::Vector{Float64})` or whatever suits you.

Comment: Thanks for presenting another viable option. Since I'm most concerned with others being able to use my functions, I'll elaborate in the original answer.

Answer (score 1):

> My preferences would be to have the user call both functions without a dot if x and y are single elements and with a .if each variable had multiple elements.

You need a function that specializes on the types of arguments. The most elegant and the fastest at execution time once compiled way to do it is with the `@generated` macro.

```
using DataFrames
@generated function f(a,b)
    if a<:Array && b<:Array
        code = quote
            DataFrame(x = a, y = b, z = a .* b)
        end
    else
        code = quote
            DataFrame(x = a, y = b, z = a * b)
        end
    end
    code
end
```

Now let us test it. Please note how the function behavior depends on the types of the arguments (`Float64` vs `Int`). Each of the parameters can be either an `Array` or a scalar.

```
julia> f(3,4)                    
1×3 DataFrame                    
│ Row │ x │ y │ z  │             
├─────┼───┼───┼────┤             
│ 1   │ 3 │ 4 │ 12 │             

julia> f(3,4.0)                  
1×3 DataFrame                    
│ Row │ x │ y   │ z    │         
├─────┼───┼─────┼──────┤         
│ 1   │ 3 │ 4.0 │ 12.0 │         

julia> f(3.0,[1,2,3])            
3×3 DataFrame                    
│ Row │ x   │ y │ z   │          
├─────┼─────┼───┼─────┤          
│ 1   │ 3.0 │ 1 │ 3.0 │          
│ 2   │ 3.0 │ 2 │ 6.0 │          
│ 3   │ 3.0 │ 3 │ 9.0 │    

julia> f([1,2,3],4)
3×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ x │ y │ z  │
├─────┼───┼───┼────┤
│ 1   │ 1 │ 4 │ 4  │
│ 2   │ 2 │ 4 │ 8  │
│ 3   │ 3 │ 4 │ 12 │      

julia> f([6,7,8],[1,2,3])        
3×3 DataFrame                    
│ Row │ x │ y │ z  │             
├─────┼───┼───┼────┤             
│ 1   │ 6 │ 1 │ 6  │             
│ 2   │ 7 │ 2 │ 14 │             
│ 3   │ 8 │ 3 │ 24 │
```